# ReferenceError: calendarId is not defined

Tags: google-sheets, calendar

New to any form of coding.
I am trying to sync Google calendars to Google sheets to autogenerate events. I found this script online but continue to have errors.
This is my current code:

```js
function scheduleShifts() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
    var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A8:C20").getValues();
    
    for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++){
        var shift = signups[x];
        var startTime = shift[0];
        var endTime = shift[1];
        var volunteer= shift[2];
        eventCal.createEvent(volunteer, startTime, endTime);
    }
}
```

The error code I keep getting is:

```js
  ReferenceError: calendarId is not defined
  scheduleShifts @ Code.gs:4
```

I can't seem to figure out how to correct it. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGXza.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`calendarID` is not equal to `calendarId`. Take a look to the `d`/`D`.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please accept it for documentation purposes.